# SQL query same exposed names

Tags: sql, correlation

There are two columns in a table `Trades`, `Id1 and Id2`, and I want to get a report that links to the persons name in `Name` table.

I want to use:

```
    INNER JOIN Name
ON Trades.Trades_Id1 = Name.NameId
    INNER JOIN Name
    ON Trades.Trades_Id2 = Name.NameId
```

I know I have to use correlation names, but even with the examples in other posts, I can't figure it out.

Comment: @MuhammedAli, on something so basic, one would only have to guess on a column name such as "name" from a names table.  The person is already showing the relationship between the tables, and all it needed was different aliases for each join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use different alias names for your user table...  Something like

```
select
      T.Trades_ID1,
      N1.Name as Trade1Name,
      T.Trades_ID2,
      N2.Name as Trade2Name
   from
      Trades T
         JOIN NAME N1 on T.Trades_ID1 = N1.NameID
         JOIN NAME N2 on T.Trades_ID2 = N2.NameID
```